# How to send emails from different custom subdomains? (sendgrid)

Tags: email, subdomain, sendgrid

I have a domain (ex:- **mydomain.com**). I am using sendgrid mail service to send and receive mails. When I send any mail using sendgrid V3 API from address **user@mydomain.com** it is working fine. But I when try to use sub-domain **user@username.mydomain.com** sendgrid throwing 403 error (domain is not authenticated). Looks like it is accepting only root domain with out any subdomains. I would like to send emails from different custom subdomains.(like **freshdesk** and **zendesk** which allocates a different sub-domain for every user). Is there any way that I can overcome this probelm ?

Any little help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the info at SendGrid's Knowledge Center, you should be able to resolve your issue by properly setting up CNAME records for your sub-domains so that they point to sendgrid.net. See https://docs.sendgrid.com/glossary/cname for details.

Comment: The result was same even after setting up CNAME record Error was Domain not authenticated. And when every time user signups a new sub-domain will allocated to him. So that he will receive all mails from that sub-domain. Adding CNAME record for every sub-domain when a new user signups is something very hard to do right ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to 1) create a sub user 2) for the newly created sub user, go to Setting -> Sender Authentication to create your subdomain.

Then you need to go to Setting -> API Key to retrieve the access token for the new sub user. And use that access token when you send email and make sure to use the From address such as user@username.mydomain.com

Answer (score 0):

You have to verify your subdomain also, similar as you verified your domain.

There will be 3 CNAME records given to you by Sendgrid which you can add into you DNS records in your domain.
(Only add first CNAME records Don't add last 2 records as it will be same as you already added for domain while domain(mydomain.com) verification

TYPE - CNAME
HOST - username.mydomain.com
VALUE - u2444223323.wl65.sendgrid.net

Answer (score 0):

Im really struggling with adding SG to a new subdomain. It works fine on domain.com but i added sub.domain.com as a verified domain, added the 3 CNAME records which were accepted, but the emails wont send.
im using a Wordpress SMTP plugin (works fine on the main domain) but the test email responds with error log

Versions:
WordPress: 6.1.1
WordPress MS: No
PHP: 8.0.28
WP Mail SMTP: 3.7.0

Params:
Mailer: sendgrid
Constants: No
Api Key: Yes

the subdomain has the correct domain listed for SG, and the correct API key.

anyone know where to start trying to fix this?